# IE7 jQuery(document).ready() problem

Tags: jquery

I have a page that works perfectly fine in Firefox, but is throwing an error in IE. I am loading jQuery dynamically (if it is not already loaded), and then doing some stuff in the jQuery(document).ready() block. However, IE throws the dreaded "Object expected" error when it hits the jQuery(document).ready() block.

You can view the full page code here: http://www.pastie.org/977767

IE is throwing the error right at jQuery(document).ready().

Any ideas as to what is going here? Again, this works perfectly fine in Firefox. It seems almost like IE thinks jQuery is loaded but it really isn't yet or that jQuery is still loading when the jQuery(document).ready() block is encountered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you append a script to the document, it is downloaded asynchronously.  In IE, the following script...

```
try{
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.getScript("/CalendarViewer/js/utils.js", function(){
        jQuery.getScript("/CalendarViewer/js/groupcatselector.js", function(){
            jQuery.getScript("/CalendarViewer/js/calendarportlet.js", function(){
                jQuery.getScript("/CalendarViewer/js/calendarportletmain.js", function(){
                    var cpm = calendarportletmain;
                    cpm.doEditDefaults("V_7f208bca412b42a68c19eb104bf46f14", "/CalendarViewer", groupCats_V_7f208bca412b42a68c19eb104bf46f14);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
}catch(err){
    alert("error in view.jsp="+err.number+" "+err.description);
}
```

...is parsed and executed before IE has finished downloading and parsing the jQuery script.  This may not be the case in Firefox if Firefox has already cached the script, it would take no time to download and can be parsed immediately.  It could the parsers working differently, Firefox parsing the script as soon as it is downloaded and IE queuing the parsing until the thread becomes idle.

You could move this code to the end of the `setUpJquery` function, which means it would only be executed when the `jQuery` object is available.  Alternatively, you could put the code inside its own function and call that function from the `setUpJquery` function.

Comment: Thanks, but the code you see is actually contained in several different files. The jQuery load scripts are used on many different pages, so I cannot put specific code in it. Is there some other way that I could put a check on jQuery(document).ready() and only have it processed once jQuery is actually loaded?

Comment: @Zendog74: You could make jQuery a synchronous part of the document.  Instead of using DOM to append, use something like `if (typeof jQuery == "undefined") document.write('<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>');`.  This would ensure that jQuery is fetched before other scripts are run.

Comment: Thanks... that did it. Definitely not as elegant, but it works. I wish IE and FFX would behave consistently on loading external scripts, sigh.

Answer (score 1):

The way i got around it was:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   document_init();
});

function document_init() {
  try{

    checkDivLoaded();

    [ ... do more stuff ... ]

  } catch( err ) {
    setTimeout('document_init()', 200);
  }
}

function checkDivLoaded() {
    if ( $('#targetDiv').length == 0) $jquery.error( 'not ready' );
}
```

It ain't pretty but it works ... it works across several files, in every browser I can think of (that I care about) and means you don't have to mess with the parent page source code. So you can keep the  clear of  tags.